# Connecting to Google cloud sql from Java stand alone application

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-sql

I want to write a java stand alone application to connect to `google cloud sql` - `MySql` database. I could find samples for app client but not for a stand alone java application.

When I tried to do this, I get the following error.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://IP:Instance_name?user=user_name");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT 1 + 1");
```

It fails with error:

No suitable driver found for `jdbc:google:mysql:..`

I see some answers where they have asked to enabled mysql connector. But it is the case with app engine project. How do I do it with stand alone application?

Comment: Can you please share your code, I am also trying to connect to Cloud SQL 2nd Gen from Stand alone java program but its not working, your code will definately help us, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the standard `mysql` connector to connect to cloud `sql` instance: e.g:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP:Instance_name?user=user_name");
```

You can check this link https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external for more information.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I missed to add my IP address to authenticate. Now it works.

Comment: Where does the database name go in this string?

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use the standard mysql java connector to connect to cloud sql form a standalone java application.

Follow the below code snippet. This should help you to connect to database seamlessly.

```
class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver);
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql//<public-ip>/<database>?useSSL=false";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);
```

Before you do this make sure you get your ipaddress from internet and add the same under the path : google cloud -> sql -> sqlinstance -> connections -> networking -> Authorized networks.

[Click here to see the google cloud mysql configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az3NL.png)

Answer (score -1):

Edit inside <> before running your code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
* A sample app that connects to a Cloud SQL instance and lists all available tables 
in a database.
*/

public class Cloud_sql {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLNonTransientConnectionException 
,IOException, SQLException {

String instanceConnectionName = <Your instanceConnectionName>;
String databaseName = <Database name from which u want to list tables>;


String IP_of_instance = <IP address of the instance>;
String username = <mysql username>;
String password = <mysql password>;

String jdbcUrl = String.format(
    "jdbc:mysql://%s/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s"
        + "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false",
IP_of_instance,
    databaseName,
    instanceConnectionName);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);

try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```